# SQL subquery exclude some elem

Tags: sql, select, subquery

I want to return the elements that have the type 6, or the type 7, or the type 5. And any of them for the same register_document_id hasn't the type 1 or 2.

register_document:

```
id        register_document_id   type_document
0         10                      5
1         10                      6
2         10                      1
3         15                      6 
4         15                      7              
5         17                      5
6         18                      2
7         18                      1
```

In that example I would like to return only the rows that it's type_document has the value 6, 7 or 5 grouping by register_document_id. By the same register_document_id I want to exclude the ones that have the type 2 and the 1.

Output query:

```
  register_document_id     type_Document
         15                     6
         15                     7
         17                     5




select x.register_document_id,x.type_document
from register_document x
where x.type_document= 6 or x.type_document = 7 or x.type_document = 5 AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM register y
    WHERE y.number_id = x.number_document AND (y.type_document <> '1' <> y.type_document <> '2'
   )
 group by x.register_document_id,x.type_document;
```

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved?

Comment: ambiguous OP... `return the elements that have the type 6, or the type 7, or the type 2 ... And any of them for the same register_document_id hasn't the type 1 or 2.` .........type 2 is ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

You need `in`!  The query should look like this:

```
select rd.register_document_id, rd.type_document
from register_document rd
where rd.type_document in (5, 6, 7) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from register_document rd2
                  where rd2.number_id = rd.number_document and
                        rd2.type_document in (1, 2)
                 );
```